Is it possible to monitor multiple services of 'notify type' for a device in react-native-ble-plx
I have the following working code:
  const monitorMultipleCharacteristics = async () => {
      try {
        
        const monitorPromises = uuids.map(({ serviceUUID, characteristicUUID }) => {
        
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            BLEService.monitorCharacteristicForDevice(
              serviceUUID,
              characteristicUUID,
              async data => {
               
                  case UUID:
                    const temperature = parse(data.value)
                    break
  
                  case UUID:
                    console.log('dispatch service')
                    break
  
                  default:
                    console.log('Unknown UUID', data.uuid)
                }
                setTimeout(resolve, 100, data)
                console.info('success', new Date().getTime())
              },
              async error => {
                console.error(error)
                await BLEService.finishMonitor()
                reject()
              }
            )
            // Store the subscription so it can be cleaned up later
            //subscriptions.push(subscription)
          })
  
          // Wait for each monitor to be set up
        })
  
        Promise.all(monitorPromises)
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error in one of the monitors:', error)
          })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error setting up characteristic monitoring:', error)
      }
  
      // Optionally return the subscriptions if you need to stop monitoring later
      //return subscriptions
    }

I am able to connect to the device. Also monitorCharacteristicForDevice for device works for one serviceUUID and characteristicUUID but I want to get it working for 5 services and charecteristics. Is this possible using the react-native-ble-plx library?
